# How do I add inputs to a running list

Tags: google-sheets

I want to take input from the cell "'I/O'!A3". Then I want to take that input, and add it to a list starting from cell "'Backups/Lists'!A3". Finally, I want to add the input to a running total and delete the original input

I tried some tutorials online, none helped

Comment: And what's the question? What **exactly** have you tried so far?

Comment: If you want to move information from one cell to another after it as been placed in a cell you need to use Google Apps Script.  A function could show it in other areas bit not move nor copy it.  Via a function it will always be a reference to the original item.